# maven repository has an invalid certificate

Tags: spring, maven, repository

I try to use the dependency on plateform-bom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.spring.plateform</groupId>
    <artifactId>plateform-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

so I add the repository of Spring

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-repo</id>
    <name>Spring Maven Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/release/</url>
 </repository>
```

but the repository has a no valid certificate so maven refuse to use it.
Is there a http instead of https repository or could you put a valid certificate on your repository ?
Best regards

here is the result of mvn command:

```
mobo7205@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/plateform/test/test-frontend$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://maven.springframework.org/release/io/spring/plateform/plateform-bom/1.0.1-RELEASE/plateform-bom-1.0.1-RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.orange.test:test-frontend:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/mobo7205/NetBeansProjects/plateform/test/test-frontend/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact io.spring.plateform:plateform-bom:pom:1.0.1-RELEASE from/to spring-repo (https://maven.springframework.org/release): hostname in certificate didn't match: <maven.springframework.org> != <repo.springsource.org> OR <repo.springsource.org> @ com.orange.test:test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, /home/mobo7205/NetBeansProjects/plateform/test/pom.xml, line 111, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar is missing. @ line 63, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: are you sure you spelt `platform` correctly?

Comment: Yes I'm sure in fact if you open the url of these repository with a browser you can also see that the certificate is invalid and you have to force it as an exception but forcing a certificate is not possible with maven practice

Comment: Do you see this error when you use maven from the command line?

Comment: this is the log of mvn command : Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact io.spring.plateform:plateform-bom:pom:1.0.1-RELEASE from/to spring-repo (https://maven.springframework.org/release): hostname in certificate didn't match: <maven.springframework.org> != <repo.springsource.org> OR <repo.springsource.org>

Comment: Please add the error message and the output of `mvn -version` to the question.

Comment: mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: /home/mobo7205/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-26-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"

Comment: I put the mvn command result inside the question, do you think that my deduction is good ?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this `hostname in certificate didn't match` problem because of an outdated Maven version, whose *HttpComponents* dependencies don't work with SNI SSL certificates.

Once I updated Maven (presumably anything better than Maven 3.2.5 should work), everything worked well again.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is a two-headed beast. On one hand, we really should use it for every service in the Internet, especially when downloading code (to make sure the code isn't tampered with on the way, for example).

On the other hand, setting up HTTPS is very expensive, hard to get right, the certificates age and the available libraries to talk to HTTPS servers are brittle, hostile and generally a mess to use.

So you can try to follow [these instructions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html) how to create a key store on your local computer. The next ugly task is to get the certificate from the server. Some browsers have support to export the certificate. Or you can use [this tool](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl-sect-client-cert.html) (which doesn't work when you are behind a proxy :-( ).

But even when you do all this, chances are it won't work because of the error you got:

> hostname in certificate didn't match

That basically means the HTTPS certificate on the server was created for a different server. Since that's usually a dead-sure sign of someone trying to hack your connection, Java refuses to connect (and rightly so).

Unfortunately, many HTTPS server are not configured correctly (or their domain name is changed by someone who doesn't understand what they are doing) so you get this error way more often than you should. And I haven't even stated talking about proxy servers.

That means you'll have to notify the people who gave you the URL and tell them that their setup is broken. Then you wait a couple of weeks until they fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Aaron I'll try to contact spring team

Comment: Makes me wonder why they don't get the same error. Maybe they're using an internal URL.

Comment: *"setting up HTTPS is very expensive"* is completely and utterly wrong - there are **free** certificates which are valid for up to one whole year. Your statements are the core reasons for newbies avoiding HTTPS - its very easy and completely free to set up ... it just takes yearly maintenance and maybe ten minutes of additional time for the first setup - if you cant afford that ... well .. you probably should not be administering dedicated servers

Comment: @specializt - I think he meant "computationally expensive" and "developer intensive to maintain" (take the existence of this question for instance), he wasn't referring to the literal cost of the cert itself.

Comment: and that is **also** wrong - neither are those certificates *"intensive to maintain"* - they literally take only 10 minutes to generate and put in place nor are they *"computationally expensive"*, generation takes about 3 seconds on modern machines and the encryption overhead for each HTTPS request is very negligible, that assumption dates back to the 1990s - in which CPU speeds **actually** were quite low, on **those** machines it made a difference, nowadays ... not in the slightest, encryption is **hardware supported** on modern CPUs

Comment: in fact, it is a somewhat founded assumption to state that most people who call HTTPS servers *"computationally expensive"* actually have some interest in unencrypted data traffic ... possibly because it makes their job easier, HTTPS **interception** is quite ... *"computationally expensive"*

Comment: @specializt I wrote that in 2014 when there was no good free source for certificates. Today, we have Let's Encrypt and others.

Comment: yet another untrue statement - free certificates have been available for DECADES now, you simply did not use google back then. One example for this may be startssl.com. Just get over it : many people distribute random BS about SSL - most of which is entirely made up. (free) SSL (web) certificates never have been expensive, hard to use, hard to get or even problematic to **any** extent whatsoever **but** certain ... people have actual interest in *unencrypted* data traffic, the NSA/BND scandal in germany gave proof of that

Answer (score -1):

Few a times even after upgrading the maven to 3.2.5 you might get the below error with respect to jackrabbit:

`[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               [ERROR]   The project com.adobe.training:company-ui:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (c:\AEM-Video-Training\company\company-ui\pom.xml) has 1 error`
`[ERROR]  Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin:0.0.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org
.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-jcr-commons:jar:2.0-alpha8 in adobe-public-releases (http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 2]`

Solution:

`1) Go to the .m2/repository/org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-jcr-commons\2.0 alpha8
 2) Rename the files to make and remove "lastupdated" from the extension. 
 jackrabbit-jcr-commons-2.0-alpha8.jar
 jackrabbit-jcr-commons-2.0-alpha8.pom
 3) run "mvn clean install -P full" and see Build and deployment successful.`