# How to add aem Uber jar dependency in maven build

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, aem, uberjar

I have used the maven archetype10 as shown below and created the project structure and everything was fine.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=10 -DarchetypeRepository=https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/
```

Now i wanted to add the aem uber-jar dependency and added the below dependency tags in the project pom.xml and in core module pom.xml respectively and also my repository tags are same as `https://repo.adobe.com/`

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

after adding the above dependency tag when i compile it is giving me the below error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project aemexample.core: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.krishh.example:aemexample.core:bundle:0.1: Could not transfer
>   artifact com.adobe.aem:uber-jar:jar:6.2.0 from/to
>   adobe-public-releases
>   (http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public): hostname in
>   certificate didn't match: `<repo.adobe.com>` != `<devedge.day.com>` OR
>   `<devedge.day.com>` -> [Help 1]

Is there anything am missing to add extra dependencies to compile and run this successfully.

Comment: https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/aem/uber-jar/ is there. So probably *hostname in certificate didn't match:* is the story.

Comment: am running it in my local instance and pointing trying to deploy by using `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage` to deploy to my **localhost:4502** author instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a classifier in your dependency. Try adding the one for AEM APIs, as [suggested in the documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html#How%20to%20I%20use%20the%20UberJar?). This should help Maven locate the necessary JAR in the repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <classifier>apis</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If that doesn't help, you should also look at the certificate warning. Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24958334/1407656) for more information on the subject.

TL;DR - possible causes could be:

- an old Maven version using an HTTP library that is not compliant with the certificate being used by the repository - try upgrading Maven
- erroneous certificate used by the server
- potential network configuration issues between you and the repository
- an actual attempt at getting you to download a malicious file by a party pretending to be the Nexus

Comment: yes added still error. `[ERROR] :Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.23 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.23: Could not transfer artifact com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:pom:0.0.23 from/to adobe (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/): hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.adobe.com> != <devedge.day.com> OR <devedge.day.com>[ERROR] Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 39, column 16`

Comment: @krish this is a problem with another artefact. It's odd, I just built a project based on the same archetype and it's using version `0.0.24` of the `content-package-maven-plugin` OOTB. Can you show this dependency as it appears in your pom?

Comment: here is my plugin version ` <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.23</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <username>${crx.username}</username>
                        <password>${crx.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>`

Comment: after changing it to **0.0.24** compilation issue solved.  but ended up with uber jar issue again `Failed to collect dependencies at com.adobe.aem:uber-jar:jar:apis:6.2.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.adobe.aem:uber-jar:jar:apis:6.2.0: Could not transfer artifact com.adobe.aem:uber-jar:pom:6.2.0 from/to adobe (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/): hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.adobe.com> != <devedge.day.com> OR <devedge.day.com> -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I can't reproduce these issues. They could have to do with your DNS settings. When I download the artefact, I can see that the certificate is using the domain `repo.adobe.com`. You seem to be reaching the same content using a different domain. Not sure where `devedge.day.come` is coming from in your case. AFAIK, the site was taken down a long time ago.

Comment: Try upgrading your maven version to latest and build.

Comment: Thanks toniedwiedz & VAr, now the issue got solved, here is my observation, with lower version of maven 3.1.1 the build is not able to pull the uber-jar dependencies. After updating to latest maven it is able to build successfully. Even content-package-maven-plugin with version 0.0.23 its able to build successfully. Thanks again

Comment: @krish a Maven upgrade was one of the answers to the question I linked to. I'll include this information in the answer itself so it's easier to find.